# Serving XHTML with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, xhtml, sinatra, mime-types, rack

I'm creating a Sinatra web application which I would like to serve mime type `application/xhtml+xml` for all web pages served. I am using Builder as template engine. Note that the application will also be serving `application/xml` for various AJAX api interfaces, also using the Builder template engine, as well as `text/css` using the scss template engine.

I notice that the webpages that get generated receive a `text/html` content type while the api interfaces get an `application/xml` content type instead. However, I don't know how the mime type is decided; presence of the `html` tag? usage of a layout or not? Whichever the case, I would like the application to issue a `application/xhtml+xml` mimetype instead of the `text/html` mime type.

I know I can specify the mime type with the `content_type` call, but I'd like to refrain from needing this in every routing function. Is there any way I can set a default mime type for a given template engine? Or can the mime type be controlled by the view's filename? Does Tilt provide any means to control mime type in a nice way?

Comment: The Sinatra docs explain a way of configuring mime types based on file extension: [Readme - Mime types](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Mime%20Types). 
You could potentially use a `before do` block and set the `content_type` that way, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Also, I added the tag `ruby` to your post, you might get more traffic that way.

Comment: Unless you’re specifically changing it somewhere, _all_ requests using Builder will have `application/xml` as the content type. Do you have a `before` or after block where you’re setting `content_type`?

Comment: matt, that's interesting because I am not changing it anywhere, yet all web pages get `text/html` and all AJAX content gets `application/xml`. I would indeed have expected everything to get `application/xml` but this does not seem to be the case for whatever reason...

Comment: Josh, I had seen that, but the mime types based on file extensions relates to static files and `send_file` as far as I can gather from the docs.

Comment: All templates rendered by `builder` should be XML, unless a content type has been specified explicitly before (this includes the `provides` condition): https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L600-601

Comment: @KonstantinHaase As I said, that's not what is happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your application is factored into separate objects, it should be straightforward to pull all of the AJAX routes into a separate Sinatra application.  This will allow you to use Sinatra's after hook.  The only requirement is for your AJAX calls to have something that identifies them as AJAX; for example, by setting a request header to a special value, or by using a specially formatted route.  Here is an example rackup file of the unique route method:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class MainApp

  def get_info params
    # return some data structure
  end

end

class MainAppRoutes < Sinatra::Base

  def initialize mainapp
    super()
    @mainapp = mainapp
  end

  get '/' do # main page
    data = @mainapp.get_info(params)
    # render response from data
  end

end

class AjaxRoutes < Sinatra::Base

  def initialize mainapp
    super()
    @mainapp = mainapp
  end

  get '/getinfo' do # handler for /ajax/getinfo
    data = @mainapp.get_info(params)
    # generate XML response from data
  end

  after do
    content_type 'application/xml'
  end

end

mainapp = MainApp.new

map '/ajax' do
  run AjaxRoutes.new(mainapp)
end
run MainAppRoutes.new(mainapp)
```

In this example, all routes starting with /ajax are handled by instances of the AjaxRoutes class.  The after hook ensures that the content type for those responses are 'application/xml'.  The non-ajax routes are not affected.

A few things to remember:

- Rack::Builder.map strips off the parts of the URL it matches.  So a '/' route in AjaxRoutes would actually answer a request for '/ajax/'.
- Always call super() in the initializers of your Sinatra-derived endpoint classes.  For Sinatra middleware, pass the first argument up (Rack calls #new with the next rack app as the first parameter).
- Review the doc about [Sinatra filters](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters).  There is a potentially frustrating quirk about modifying responses with the after hook.

Comment: How does this help me? The AJAX stuff is not a separate app. I have one app which shares data needed between webpages, AJAX content as well as style sheets, each of these three should give their own mime type. And by the way, the AJAX stuff would be `application/xml` not `application/xhtml+xml`, that would be the web pages.

Comment: An app refers to a Rack endpoint, its not a completely isolated entity.  If you don't understand Rack, and cannot extrapolate from the approach I outlined above, I'll happily remove my answer.

Comment: Catnapper, could you provide a slightly more outlined example of what you mean? I'm not that familiar yet with Rack and Sinatra.

Comment: There are so many ways to tackle this, and the best approach depends on what you're doing.  Application structure matters - is the business logic all contained in the Sinatra route code, or is it separated out into other objects?  Are you setting request headers with each AJAX call?

Comment: I'm trying to separate all business code out into separate objects, the application object receives some instance variables (@foo) to communicate data to templates, I am not setting any headers anywhere.

Comment: Elaborated on the basic approach - I think the separate Sinatra app is the way to go for well-factored programs.  The middlware version of this also works well.